# Python Flask WTForms ensure uniqueness of a field

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

I am using flask with WTForms to create online form. In this form I have a section where user has 10 dropdown menus (with same content; they need to rank items). I'd like to ensure that the same item is not selected multiple times. However, I can't find a way to do so. In WTForms there is a validator `Equals()` which checks if the field equals to another field, but no such validator to check if it does not equal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own validator and use it as you wish.

Comment: Any suggestions on how would I go around doing that? I have seen that this is possible but can I/how can I access data in the other fields?

Thanks